# logistic regression using more than one predictor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, logistic-regression

I want to fit a logistic regression model that predicts Y using X1 and X2.
What I know is that we use the following method:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size)
```

and then

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

To predict Y using X, I don't know how to train the data using more than one predictor. Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are 2 features `X1` and `X2`, then the training data `X` will have 2 columns. For example if data has 1000 `X1` and 1000 `X2`, then the shape of `X` should be (1000 x 2)

For example you have a csv file with 3 columns: `X1`, `X2`, `y`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
X = df[['X1', 'X2']]
Y = df['y']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.concatenate` and join a sequence of X1 & X2 along row then use LogisticRegression:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X1 = np.random.rand(100,3) #-> shape=(100,3)
X2 = np.random.rand(100,4) #-> shape=(100,4)
Y = np.random.randint(0,2,100)

X = np.concatenate((X1, X2), axis=1)
print(X.shape)
# (100, 7)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=.33)
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
clf.predict(x_test)
```